Flajolet-Martin algorithm error estimate
I'm studying the Flajolet-Martin algorithm for counting distinct elements in a wider set of elements, but I got stuck trying to understand the error estimate of the algorithm.

Here d is the real number of distinct element that the algorithm tries to approximate. What i'm not understanding is the part in red: how does $d/2^{logd+c}$ become $1/2^c$
Thanks in advance

Well, we have
$$
\frac{d}{2^{\lceil \log_2 d \rceil + c}}=
\frac{2^{\log_2 d}}{2^{\lceil \log_2 d \rceil + c}}=\frac{2^{-\epsilon}}{2^c}\leq 2^{-c}
$$
for some $\epsilon \in [0,1),$ where $\epsilon=\log_2 d-\lceil \log_2 d \rceil.$

Thank you, for some reason i thought it was a base 10 logarithm
